# Meaning of "well-capitalized litigation"

Tags: meaning, expressions

In the following sentence:

> Smart contracts will automatically execute the terms of any deal, without getting bogged down by human fickleness or well-capitalized litigation.

I understand the fickle nature of human beings may bog down the execution of the terms of a deal.

But what about the expression "well-capitalized litigation"?

I know that the term litigation refers to the source of disagreement between the parts in a deal.

Would a well-capitalized litigation mean a high amount of money is under dispute? And that situation would make things complex enough to bog down the execution of the deal?

Thanks!

Comment: It just means "well-funded"—that is, paid for by a wealthy litigant who is willing to spend lots of money prosecuting or defending against a lawsuit in order to wear down his or her opponent.

Comment: *A pending litigation claim is, practically speaking, a “receivable,” albeit a contingent one. From an accounting perspective, when a company is owed money by someone, it almost always creates a balance sheet asset — a receivable. Money spent to collect that receivable is often added to its asset value, or “capitalized.“* "Cost Comparison for Financing Litigation," TodaysGeneralCounsel https://www.todaysgeneralcounsel.com/cost-comparison-financing-litigation/

Comment: This Q is better asked on Accounting related SE.

Answer (score -1):

You appear to understand the individual terms, so I’ll skip the dictionary definitions.

*Litigation* refers to *being* sued. The reference to “without getting bogged down” strongly indicates the direction of the (potential) litigation.

*Well-capitalised* here refers to the finances available to the other party.

The assertion is that “smart contracts” help avoid getting sued by wealthy entities.